# Using STORAGE macro using QSAM for input/output

Tags: memory-management, assembly

I was wondering if you can help me out. I wanted to know if there is an easier way to do the following. My code works but I feel like there is a lot things going out with multiple loops and wanted to see if anyone can help me condense the code i have attached to make it clear.

In my code I have created 3 subroutines (insert, delete, and print).

Goals:

Each line in the file is 40 bytes long and contains: one letter X in column 1, a positive integer K which is 5 digits long in columns 3-7, and spaces in columns 6-40.

Using the STORAGE macro request space for a table of 20 packed-decimal integers, each 3 bytes long. Initialize all of the table to the value -1.
Store the address of the table in a fullword variable(used TABLEADD in my code), store the size of the table in a fullword variabl(used TABSIZE in my code).
Declare a fullword variable named something like INUSE to store the current number of values in the table.

- If X = 'I', insert the number K into the table at the end and update INUSE.
- If X = 'P', print the contents of the entire table (including the -1s at the end, if any) with 5 numbers per line. (Ignore the value of K on this line.)
- If X = 'D', delete one number from the beginning of the table, move the remaining numbers up to the beginning and update INUSE.

(Bear in mind that the unused part of the table should all be -1s.)

```
//KC03LA JOB ,'R',MSGCLASS=H,REGION=2048K                  
//STEP1 EXEC PROC=ASMACLG                                                             
//C.SYSLIB DD DSN=SYS1.MACLIB,DISP=SHR                                  
//         DD DSN=KC02293.SYS2.MACLIB,DISP=SHR                          
//C.SYSIN DD *                                                          
MAIN     CSECT                                                          
 PRINT NOGEN                   
 STM   14,12,12(13)            
 LR    12,15                   
 USING MAIN,12                 
 LA    14,MAINSAVE             
 ST    13,4(0,14)              
 ST    14,8(0,13)              
 LR    13,14                   
*                                      
 OPEN  (INDCB,(INPUT))         
 LTR   15,15                   
 BZ    OPEN10K                 
 ABEND 222,DUMP                
*                                      
OPEN10K  OPEN  (OUTDCB,(OUTPUT))       
 LTR   15,15                   
 BZ    OPEN20K                 
 ABEND 333,DUMP                
*                                      
OPEN20K  DS    0H                      
 LA    1,OBTMEM                
 BAL   11,ALCTE                
*                                      
LOOP1    GET   INDCB,BUFFER            
 CLI   EOFFLAG,C'Y'            
*                                      
 BZ    ENDLOOP                 
 CLI   BUFFER,C'P'                                              
 BZ    PRINTCLL                                                 
 CLI   BUFFER,C'I'                                              
 BZ    INSRTCLL                                                 
 CLI   BUFFER,C'D'                                              
 BZ    DELTECLL                                                 
 B     LOOP1                                                    
*                                                                       
 PRINTCLL DS    0H                                                       
 LA    1,PRNTPLST                                               
 BAL   11,PRNT                                                  
 B     LOOP1                                                    
*                                                                       
INSRTCLL DS    0H                                                       
 PACK  NBR(3),BUFFER+2(5)                                       
 PUT   OUTDCB,=CL80'CALLING INSERT'                             
*                                                                       
 LA    1,INSTPLST                                               
 BAL   11,INSRT                                                 
 B     LOOP1                                                    
*                                                                       
DELTECLL DS    0H                                                       
 PUT   OUTDCB,=CL80'CALLING DELETE'                             
 LA    1,INSTPLST                                               
 BAL   11,DELTE                                                 
 B     LOOP1                                                    
*                                                                       
ENDLOOP  DS    0H                                                       
*                                                                       
 L     9,TABSIZE                                                
 SR    4,4                                                      
 M     4,=F'3'                                                  
 STORAGE RELEASE,LENGTH=(5),ADDR=TABLEADD                       
*                                                                       
 CLOSE (INDCB)               
 LTR   15,15                 
 BZ    CLOSE10K              
 ABEND 555,DUMP              
*                                    
CLOSE10K CLOSE (OUTDCB)              
 LTR   15,15                 
 BZ    CLOSE20K              
 ABEND 666,DUMP              
*                                                                       
CLOSE20K DS    0H                                                       
*                                                                       
 L     13,4(0,13)                                               
 LM    14,12,12(13)                                             
 BR    14                                                       
 LTORG                                                          
***************************************************************         
MAINSAVE DS    18F'-1'                 
NBR      DS    PL3                     
TABLEADD DC    F'0'                    
TABSIZE  DC    F'0'                    
TMPSIZE  DC    F'0'                    
INUSE    DC    F'0'                    
BUFFER   DC    40C' '                  
EMPTY    DC    80C' '                  
*                                                                       
OBTMEM   DC    A(TABLEADD)                                              
 DC    A(TMPSIZE)                                               
 DC    A(TABSIZE)                                               
 DC    A(INUSE)                                                 
*                                                                       
PRNTPLST DC    A(TABLEADD)                                              
 DC    A(TMPSIZE)                                               
*                                                                       
INSTPLST DC    A(TABLEADD)                                              
 DC    A(TMPSIZE)                                               
 DC    A(INUSE)                                                 
 DC    A(NBR)                                                   
*                                                                       
***************************************************************         
 INDCB    DCB   DDNAME=INPUT,                                  X
       DEVD=DA,                                                X
       DSORG=PS,                                               X
       MACRF=GM,                                               X
       RECFM=FB,                                               X
       LRECL=40,                                               X
       EODAD=EOF1                                               
*                                                                       
EOFFLAG  DC    C'N'                                                     
*                                                                       
EOF1     MVI   EOFFLAG,C'Y'                                             
 BR    14                                                       
*                                                                       
OUTDCB   DCB   DDNAME=OUTPUT,                                  X
       DEVD=DA,                                                X
       DSORG=PS,                                               X
       MACRF=PM,                                               X
       RECFM=FBA,                                              X
       LRECL=80                                                 
*                                                                       
***********INSERT SUBROUTINE***********************************         
INSRT  DS    0H                                                       
 STM   2,8,ISAVE                                                
 ST    11,RSAVE                                                 
 LM    2,5,0(1)                                                 
 L     6,0(0,3)                                                 
 L     7,0(0,4)                                                 
 CR    6,7                                                      
 BE    RESIZE                                                   
DONE   DS    0H                                                       
 L     6,0(0,2)                                                 
 L     7,0(0,4)                                                 
 LTR   7,7                                                      
 BZ    ADD                                                      
 LR    8,7                                                      
RPT    LA    6,3(0,6)                                                 
 BCT   8,RPT                                                    
ADD    DS    0H                                                       
 ZAP   0(3,6),0(3,5)                                            
 LA    7,1(0,7)                                                 
 ST    7,0(0,4)                                                 
 LM    2,8,ISAVE                                                
 L     11,RSAVE                                                 
 BR    11                                                       
*                                                                       
RESIZE DS    0H                                                       
 SLA   6,1(0)                                                   
 ST    6,TMPSIZE                                                
 LA    1,OBTMEM                                                 
 BAL   11,ALCTE                                                 
 PUT   OUTDCB,=80C' '
 PUT   OUTDCB,=CL80'WE HAVE ALLOCATED MORE MEMORY FOR THE TABLE'                
 PUT   OUTDCB,=80C' '                                           
 PUT   OUTDCB,=CL80'WE HAVE DELETED OLD TABLE'                  
 PUT   OUTDCB,=80C' '                                    
 B     DONE                                                     
 LTORG                                                          
***********INSERT STORAGE**************************************         
ISAVE  DS    7F                                                       
RSAVE  DS    F                                                        
***********DELETE SUBROUTINE***********************************         
DELTE  DS    0H                                                       
 STM   2,8,DSAVE                                                
 ST    11,DELTSAVE                                              
 LM    2,4,0(1)                                                 
 L     6,0(0,2)                                                 
 L     5,0(0,3)                                                 
 L     7,0(0,4)                                                 
 LTR   8,7                                                      
 BZ    FNSH                                                     
RPT1   ZAP   0(3,6),3(3,6)                                            
 LA    6,3(0,6)                                                 
 BCT   6,RPT1                                                   
 DS    0H                                                       
 BCTR  7,0                                                      
 ST    7,0(0,4)                                                 
 SRA   5,1(0)                                                   
 CR    7,5                                                      
 BL    DCR                                                      
FNSH   DS    0H                                                       
*                                                                       
 LM    2,8,DSAVE                                                
 L     11,DELTSAVE                                              
 BR    11                                                       
*                                                                       
DCR    DS    0H                                                       
 ST    5,TMPSIZE                                                
 LA    1,OBTMEM                                                 
 BAL   11,ALCTE                                                 
 PUT   OUTDCB,=80C' '                                           
 PUT   OUTDCB,=CL80'WE HAVE ALLOCATED NEW TABLE'                
 PUT   OUTDCB,=80C' '                                           
 PUT   OUTDCB,=CL80'WE HAVE DELETED OLD TABLE'                  
 PUT   OUTDCB,=80C' '                                           
 B     FNSH                                                     
***********DELETE STORAGE**************************************         
DSAVE    DS    7F                                                       
DELTSAVE DS    F                                                        
***************************************************************         
ALCTE    DS    0H                                                       
 STM   2,7,ASAVE                                                
 LM    2,5,0(1)                                                 
 L     3,0(0,3)                                                 
 L     5,0(0,5)                                                 
 LR    7,3                                                      
 SR    6,6                                                      
 M     6,=F'3'                                                  
 STORAGE OBTAIN,LENGTH=(7),ADDR=TMPADD,COND=YES                 
 LTR   15,15                                                    
 BZ    DOWN                                                     
 ABEND 123,DUMP                                                 
DOWN   L     6,TMPADD                                                 
 LR    7,3                                                      
BEGN   ZAP   0(3,6),=PL1'-1'                                          
 LA    6,3(0,6)                                                 
 BCT   7,BEGN                                                   
 LTR   5,5                                                      
 BZ    JUMP                                                     
 L     6,TMPADD                                                 
 L     7,0(0,2)                                                 
DUPL   ZAP   0(3,6),0(3,7)                                            
 LA    6,3(0,6)                                                 
 LA    7,3(0,7)                                                 
 BCT   5,DUPL                                                   
JUMP   L     7,0(4)                                                   
 LTR   7,7                                                      
 BZ    SKIP                                                     
 L     7,0(0,2)                                                 
 STORAGE RELEASE,LENGTH=(5),ADDR=(7)                            
SKIP   L     6,TMPADD                                                 
 ST    6,0(2)                                                   
 ST    3,0(4)                                                   
*                                                                       
 LM    2,7,ASAVE                                                
 BR    11                                                       
 LTORG                                                          
************ALLOCATION STORAGE*********************************         
ASAVE    DS    6F                                                       
TMPADD   DS    F                                                        
************PRINT SUBROUTINE***********************************         
PRNT     DS    0H                                                       
 STM   2,5,PSAVE                                                
 LM    2,3,0(1)                                                 
 PUT   OUTDCB,=80C' '                                           
 PUT   OUTDCB,=CL80'         NUMBERS LIST'                      
 PUT   OUTDCB,=80C' '                                           
 LA    4,OLINE                                                  
 SR    5,5                                                      
 L     2,0(0,2)                                                 
 L     3,0(0,3)                                                 
 LTR   3,3                                                      
 BZ    TOP1                                                     
AGAIN    DS    0H                                                       
 MVC   0(7,4),PAT                                               
 ED    0(7,4),0(2)                                              
 LA    2,3(0,2)                                                 
 C     5,=F'4'                                                  
 BZ    NEXT1                                                    
 LA    4,8(0,4)                                                 
 LA    5,1(0,5)                                                 
 B     BOTTOM1                                                  
NEXT1    PUT   OUTDCB,OLINE                                             
 MVI   OLINE,C' '                                               
 MVC   OLINE+1(79),OLINE                                        
 LA    4,OLINE                                                  
 SR    5,5                                                      
BOTTOM1  BCT   3,AGAIN                                                  
*                                                                       
TOP1     PUT   OUTDCB,=80C' '                                           
 LM    2,5,PSAVE                                                
 BR    11                                                       
 LTORG                                                          
***********PRINT STORAGE***************************************         
PSAVE    DS    4F                                                       
OLINE    DC    80C' '                                                   
PAT      DC    X'40202020212060'                                        
***************************************************************         
 END   MAIN                                                     
/*                                                                      
//L.SYSLIB DD DSN=KC02293.SYS2.CALLIB,DISP=SHR                          
//G.INPUT  DD DSN=KC02314.SPRING16.CSCI641.HW4ADATA,DISP=SHR            
//G.OUTPUT DD DSN=&&TEMP,DISP=(NEW,PASS,DELETE)                         
//G.XSNAPOUT DD SYSOUT=*                                                
//G.XPRNT DD SYSOUT=*                                                   
//*                                                                     
//*                                                                     
//STEP2   EXEC PGM=IEBPTPCH                                             
//SYSTU1  DD DSN=&&TEMP,DISP=(OLD,DELETE)                               
//SYSTU2  DD SYSOUT=*                                                   
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                                  
//SYSIN    DD *                                                         
 PRINT MAXFLDS=1                                                    
 RECORD FIELD=(80)                                                  
/*                                                                      
//
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some great answers.

Comment: A lot of what separates the men from the boys in assembler programming is about getting the core concepts right. If things like your entry/exit linkages work cleanly and you have consistent ways to define and call subroutines, you're way ahead of the game. Go a step further and make your whole program reentrant. Create some macros for program and subroutine linkage. Add a bit of error handling (for example, your OPENs may well fail on various 013 abends...how about handling them versus just dying?)...with this stuff out of the way, the logic you're looking to implement gets a lot simpler.